# How to add image to beamer footline and keep it align with the text?

Tags: beamer, graphics, header-footer

I want to add an image to my footline and aligned with the text of the same footline.

I have the following in my beamertheme.

```
\def\logo{%
\resizebox{!}{2.5ex}{\includegraphics{logo-small.png}}
}

\mode<presentation>
\defbeamertemplate*{footline}{example theme}
{%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex,%
        leftskip=.3cm,rightskip=.3cm plus1fil]{separation line}
        \usebeamerfont{section in head/foot}%
        \insertshortauthor\hfill\insertshorttitle\hfill\logo
    \end{beamercolorbox}
}
\mode
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1192/how-do-i-mark-code-blocks). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: Well, what kind of alignment do you want exactly? You can modify the image height using `\raisebox{<amount>}{<content>}`. Please always add a complete but [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that). Thanks.

Comment: @MartinScharrer: Since your suggestion solved the issue, perhaps you should post that as an answer so this can be marked as answered.

Comment: @PeterGrill: Done

Answer (score 4):

You can modify the image height using `\raisebox{<amount>}{<content>}`. The `\resizebox{!}{2.5ex}{...}` is actually not required, you can use the `width` key of `\includegraphics` macro for the resizing:

```
\def\logo{%
  \raisebox{<amount>}{\includegraphics[width=2.5ex]{logo-small.png}}%
}
```

---

You could also load the `adjustbox` package with the `export` option, then you can use the `raise` key with `\includegraphics`:

```
\def\logo{%
  \includegraphics[width=2.5ex,raise=<amount>]{logo-small.png}%
}
```

Comment: _You could also load the adjustbox package with the `export` option_ – cool, didn't know about that and just figured that there is a new version of `adjustbox` available. Very useful!